# No (USB3) camera device on ubuntu

Tags: camera, usb, ubuntu-16.04

After installing the necessary driver, mvBlueFox3 camera is well detected according to demsg (ubutnu 16.04).  However, when I launch factory GUI, I get the error message telling "No Device"...

The provided log scripts have generated these error messages:

```
<logmsg ts="423100378" td="56" procId="6175" df="3" msg="enumerate: Call to 'LibraryAdapter::instance()-#plibusb_open_( ppDeviceList_[i], #hDevice )' failed. Error: -3(LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS).
" />
<logmsg ts="423100381" td="3" procId="6175" df="3" msg="enumerate: Call to 'LibraryAdapter::instance()-#plibusb_open_( ppDeviceList_[i], #hDevice )' failed. Error: -3(LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS).
" />
```

Has anyone an idea on the source of the problem....?
Am stuck on this issue since a couple of days already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is permissions error. if you launch the factory GUI with root privileges `sudo`  it will work

( http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/325416/why-do-i-get-libusb-error-access-when-trying-toget-my-xbox-controller-working )

you can write a `udev` rule if you do not want to launch the program as root, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72437/how-to-grant-non-root-user-access-to-device-files